# Cómo cambiar la informacion de una tabla por medio de una etiqueta <select></select> con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo web, la cuestion es que tengo una tabla en HTML, tambien tengo una etiqueta tipo < select > y un < input >, mi idea es la siguiente:

- se ingresa la cantidad de filas con el < input >
- se selecciona que contenido mostrar en la tabla con el < select > (el contenido son dos arreglos definidos en js) y apartir de esta informacion, se llena la tabla

en js tengo una funcion que recibe un parametro (el tipo de contenido del < select > para recorrer el arreglo correspondiente)
tengo un evento tipo "change" a la etiqueta del < select > y un if que evalua el valor actual del < select > y dependiendo del valor se llama a la funcion con el arreglo correspondiente

mi problema es, la primera vez que ejecuto el codigo, si me funciona, pero si despues selecciono otra opcion no me cambia los valores de la tabla

```js
const cantidadProductos = document.querySelector("#cantidadProductos");
const tipoProducto = document.querySelector("#tipo-producto");
const tablaFactura = document.querySelector("#tablaFactura");
const txtIsv = document.querySelector("#isv");
const txtExento = document.querySelector("#exento");
const txtGrabado = document.querySelector("#grabado");
const txtTotal = document.querySelector("#total");

let totalPrecioProductos = 0;
let isv = 0.15;
let exento = 0;
let grabado = 0;
let contador = 0;
const productosGrabados = [{
    nombre: "azucar",
    precio: "25",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pollo",
    precio: "33",
  },
  {
    nombre: "arroz",
    precio: "15",
  },
];

const productosExentos = [{
    nombre: "camera",
    precio: "550",
  },
  {
    nombre: "cobijas",
    precio: "350",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pantalon gino ferreti",
    precio: "750",
  },
];

const cantidadMinima = 1;
const cantidadMaxima = 5;

//obtiene el valor de la cantidad de productos
var cantidad = cantidadProductos.value;

txtIsv.textContent = 0;
txtExento.textContent = 0;
txtGrabado.textContent = 0;
txtTotal.textContent = 0;

function calcularFactura(tipo_producto) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {

    tipo_producto.forEach((p) => {

      if (contador < cantidad) {
        const cantidadRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidadMaxima - cantidadMinima + 1)) + cantidadMinima;

        let fila = document.createElement("tr");
        let td = document.createElement("td");

        td.innerText = cantidadRandom;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.nombre;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.precio;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = cantidadRandom * parseInt(p.precio);
        totalPrecioProductos += parseFloat((p.precio * cantidadRandom), 2);
        fila.appendChild(td);

        cuerpoTabla.appendChild(fila);

        contador++;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  if (tipo_producto === 'grabado') {
    grabado = totalPrecioProductos / 1.15;
    isv = totalPrecioProductos - grabado;

    txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
    txtGrabado.textContent = grabado.toFixed(2);
    txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    isv = totalPrecioProductos * 0.15;
    exento = totalPrecioProductos - isv

    txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
    txtExento.textContent = exento.toFixed(2)
    txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
  }
}

let cuerpoTabla = document.createElement("tbody");
tablaFactura.appendChild(cuerpoTabla);



tipoProducto.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let valor = event.target.value

  if (event.target.value === "exento") {
    calcularFactura(productosExentos);

  } else if (event.target.value === 'grabado') {
    calcularFactura(productosGrabados);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container bg-danger-subtle border-5">
  <div class="header text-center pt-5">
    <h1>Cantidad de Productos</h1>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="cantidadProductos" id="cantidadProductos" />
  </div>

  <div class="p-2">
    <select id="tipo-producto" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Seleccionar el tipo de producto</option>
      <option value="grabado">grabado</option>
      <option value="exento">exento</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="factura pt-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Factura</h1>

    <div class="factura-body">
      <table id="tablaFactura" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Producto</th>
            <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>

      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-end">
        <p class="float-end font">
          ISV <span id="isv" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Exento <span id="exento" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Grabado
          <span id="grabado" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Total <span id="total" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Observación no menor: la palabra en este caso debe ser _gravado_, no _grabado_ (viene de _gravamen_: _tasa_, _impuesto_). Por otra parte: la idea es que cuando cambies entre la opciones del select, ¿se creen nuevas filas? No me queda claro, ya que al ejecutar el snippet, no se ven cambios.

Comment: -1000 en gramática, gracias por la observación. Sii, la idea es esa, cuando seleccione otra opcion del select, deberia mostrarse el arreglo de gravado o el arreglo de exento. Y veo que el snippet no funciona, pero de manera local si me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás declarando la cantidad de productos inicialmente, y ésta se queda como un valor vacío. Tienes que declararla dentro de la función.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const cantidadProductos = document.querySelector("#cantidadProductos");
const tipoProducto = document.querySelector("#tipo-producto");
const tablaFactura = document.querySelector("#tablaFactura");
const txtIsv = document.querySelector("#isv");
const txtExento = document.querySelector("#exento");
const txtGrabado = document.querySelector("#grabado");
const txtTotal = document.querySelector("#total");

let totalPrecioProductos = 0;
let isv = 0.15;
let exento = 0;
let grabado = 0;
let contador = 0;
const productosGrabados = [{
    nombre: "azucar",
    precio: "25",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pollo",
    precio: "33",
  },
  {
    nombre: "arroz",
    precio: "15",
  },
];

const productosExentos = [{
    nombre: "camera",
    precio: "550",
  },
  {
    nombre: "cobijas",
    precio: "350",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pantalon gino ferreti",
    precio: "750",
  },
];

const cantidadMinima = 1;
const cantidadMaxima = 5;


txtIsv.textContent = 0;
txtExento.textContent = 0;
txtGrabado.textContent = 0;
txtTotal.textContent = 0;

function calcularFactura(tipo_producto) {
  var cantidad = cantidadProductos.value;
  for (let i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
    tipo_producto.forEach((p) => {
      if (contador < cantidad) {
        const cantidadRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidadMaxima - cantidadMinima + 1)) + cantidadMinima;

        let fila = document.createElement("tr");
        let td = document.createElement("td");

        td.innerText = cantidadRandom;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.nombre;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = p.precio;
        fila.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = cantidadRandom * parseInt(p.precio);
        totalPrecioProductos += parseFloat((p.precio * cantidadRandom), 2);
        fila.appendChild(td);

        cuerpoTabla.appendChild(fila);

        contador++;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  if (tipo_producto === 'grabado') {
    grabado = totalPrecioProductos / 1.15;
    isv = totalPrecioProductos - grabado;

    txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
    txtGrabado.textContent = grabado.toFixed(2);
    txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    isv = totalPrecioProductos * 0.15;
    exento = totalPrecioProductos - isv

    txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
    txtExento.textContent = exento.toFixed(2)
    txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
  }
}

let cuerpoTabla = document.createElement("tbody");
tablaFactura.appendChild(cuerpoTabla);



tipoProducto.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let valor = event.target.value
  if (event.target.value === "exento") {
    calcularFactura(productosExentos);

  } else if (event.target.value === 'grabado') {
    calcularFactura(productosGrabados);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container bg-danger-subtle border-5">
  <div class="header text-center pt-5">
    <h1>Cantidad de Productos</h1>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="cantidadProductos" id="cantidadProductos" />
  </div>

  <div class="p-2">
    <select id="tipo-producto" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Seleccionar el tipo de producto</option>
      <option value="grabado">grabado</option>
      <option value="exento">exento</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="factura pt-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Factura</h1>

    <div class="factura-body">
      <table id="tablaFactura" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Producto</th>
            <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>

      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-end">
        <p class="float-end font">
          ISV <span id="isv" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Exento <span id="exento" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Grabado
          <span id="grabado" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Total <span id="total" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Por otra parte, tu código se puede mejorar en varios puntos:

- No es necesario pasar en parámetro aquellos elementos que están en el ámbito global. En ese sentido, tú puedes pasar el tipo de producto elegido a la función, y dentro de ella elegir el conjunto de elementos que aplique (usaremos un bloque `switch ... case` para ello).
- Conviene que el `tbody` sea definido en el HTML, y luego guardar una referencia del mismo para modificarlo.
- Cada variable debe ser declarada en su ámbito. Por ejemplo, en tu código original declaras las variables de los cálculos y el contador en el ámbito global. Esos valores se usarán y cambiarán solamente dentro de la función, por tanto, deberían ser declarados allí.
- La práctica recomendada cuando agregas elementos dinámicos es usar [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment), para evitar que el DOM se vuelva a renderizar cada vez que agregas una nueva fila en la tabla.
- Agregamos una función `resetElements()` para limpiar el `tbody` y los valores calculados en cada cambio.

Con esas mejoras, el código quedaría así:

```js
const cantidadProductos = document.querySelector("#cantidadProductos");
const tipoProducto = document.querySelector("#tipo-producto");
const tablaFactura = document.querySelector("#tablaFactura");
const cuerpoTabla = document.querySelector('#tablaFactura tbody');
const txtIsv = document.querySelector("#isv");
const txtExento = document.querySelector("#exento");
const txtGrabado = document.querySelector("#grabado");
const txtTotal = document.querySelector("#total");

const productosGrabados = [{
    nombre: "azucar",
    precio: "25",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pollo",
    precio: "33",
  },
  {
    nombre: "arroz",
    precio: "15",
  },
];

const productosExentos = [{
    nombre: "camera",
    precio: "550",
  },
  {
    nombre: "cobijas",
    precio: "350",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pantalon gino ferreti",
    precio: "750",
  },
];

const cantidadMinima = 1;
const cantidadMaxima = 5;

function calcularFactura(tipo_producto) {
  var productos = false;
  let totalPrecioProductos = 0;
  switch (tipo_producto) {
    case 'grabado':
      productos = productosGrabados;
      break;
    case 'exento':
      productos = productosExentos;
      break;
  }
  if (productos) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let cantidad = cantidadProductos.value;
    let contador = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
      productos.forEach((p) => {
        if (contador < cantidad) {
          const cantidadRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cantidadMaxima - cantidadMinima + 1)) + cantidadMinima;
          let fila = document.createElement("tr");
          let td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerText = cantidadRandom;
          fila.appendChild(td);
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerText = p.nombre;
          fila.appendChild(td);
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerText = p.precio;
          fila.appendChild(td);
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerText = cantidadRandom * parseInt(p.precio);
          totalPrecioProductos += parseFloat((p.precio * cantidadRandom), 2);
          fila.appendChild(td);
          fragment.appendChild(fila);
          contador++;
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
    }

    cuerpoTabla.appendChild(fragment);
    if (tipo_producto === 'grabado') {
      let grabado = totalPrecioProductos / 1.15;
      let isv = totalPrecioProductos - grabado;
      txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
      txtGrabado.textContent = grabado.toFixed(2);
      txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
    } else {
      let isv = totalPrecioProductos * 0.15;
      let exento = totalPrecioProductos - isv
      txtTotal.textContent = totalPrecioProductos.toFixed(2);
      txtExento.textContent = exento.toFixed(2)
      txtIsv.textContent = isv.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}

function resetElements() {
  txtIsv.textContent = 0;
  txtExento.textContent = 0;
  txtGrabado.textContent = 0;
  txtTotal.textContent = 0;
  cuerpoTabla.innerHTML = "";
}


tipoProducto.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let valor = event.target.value
  if (valor === "exento" || valor === "grabado") {
    resetElements();
    calcularFactura(valor);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container bg-danger-subtle border-5">
  <div class="header text-center pt-5">
    <h1>Cantidad de Productos</h1>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="cantidadProductos" id="cantidadProductos" value=2/>
  </div>

  <div class="p-2">
    <select id="tipo-producto" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Seleccionar el tipo de producto</option>
      <option value="grabado">grabado</option>
      <option value="exento">exento</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="factura pt-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Factura</h1>

    <div class="factura-body">
      <table id="tablaFactura" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Producto</th>
            <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>

      </table>

      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-end">
        <p class="float-end font">
          ISV <span id="isv" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Exento <span id="exento" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Grabado
          <span id="grabado" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
        <p class="float-end font">
          Total <span id="total" class="px-5 font-weight-bold"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar y corregir mi código, tomaré en cuenta tus consejos para mis próximas prácticas :)